# Posting an image on a Friend's wall with Facebook SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I can post a message on a friend's Facebook wall, but I want to post an Image. What do I need to add to my code?

Here is my current code:

```
[[FBRequestWrapper defaultManager] sendFBRequestWithGraphPath:_graphPath params:
  [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Post on wall :)" forKey:@"message"]
andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to post to the user's photo album with a caption. To do this you will need to add additional parameters to the dictionary:

```
[[FBRequestWrapper defaultManager] sendFBRequestWithGraphPath:_graphPath params:
   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Post on wall :)", @"message", image, @"source"] andDelegate:self];
```

`image` is the `UIImage` you wish to post.

You need to also make sure that the `_graphpath` points to the users photo album: `@"me/photos"`